# Extreme fuzzy matching in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I am currently trying to write a program which does extremely fuzzy matching in MySQL. Basically, I have a string and a table. What I need to do is match the words between the two and order them by how many match.

For example, I might have the following:

For search string: 'Epson Printer R300'

and the rows in the db:

1: 'Epson Stylus Photo R300 Printer'

2: 'Epson Random Scanner'

3: 'Epson Stylus R450 Printer'

4: 'HP Digimax'

**Many above do not exist. If anyone was googling any of them and got this page, I am very sorry :)

What I want is to get it to match them so that it would see that row 1 matches 3 words, row 2 matches 1, row 3 matches 2, and 4 matches none. An added bonus would be to then order them by how many of these match (though this does not necessarily need to be done).

So far I have tried to use the normal fuzzy matching, with '%Epson Printer R300% LIKE item', and even as far as to put % in where the spaces are. I would assume I need to somehow make it so each word does not necessarily need to be in it, and make it so it does not care about the order the words come in.

As for further things I could try include writing a program in C to take everything out of the DB and manually process it, however as this is for a website it is preferable that this doesn't happen.

Does anyone have any ideas of how I could do this? Or is it impossible/very difficult?

Thanks!

Comment: I suppose I could use REGEXP - but is there any way I can order by the number of items matched with this? ie [(word)(otherword).]+ and count how many word and otherword I get?

Comment: Have you looked at [FULL-TEXT search](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html)?

Comment: Just looking at it, it seems to do the correct sort of thing. Is there a way that I can concatenate a bunch of different columns and use them in the match? And a way to organize by how many times it is contained within?

Comment: Whoops, apparently I cannot read - the concatenate bit is a csv in match()! Thanks!

Comment: Yes, you can create a FULL-TEXT index on multiple columns and specify the columns in the `MATCH ... AGAINST` statement.

Comment: Thanks! Even better, it can do 'WITH QUERY EXPANSION' which makes the results better!